# DB2 user defined functions and custom schema

Tags: c++, c, db2, command-line-interface

I create a custom schema in my DB2 database using the following command:

`db2 create schema MYSCHEMA authorization db2user`
(db2user is the OS user)

Then through my application I install some functions in this schema, they seems to be installed properly:

```
db2 => select substr(funcschema,1,12)as funcs, substr(funcname,1,30) as func from    syscat.functions where funcschema='MYSCHEMA' order by 1,2

FUNCS         FUNC
------------  ------------------------------
MYSCHEMA      NUMCAST
MYSCHEMA      NUMSORT

2 record(s) selected.
```

But queries which has to use these functions fails.

`SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "NUMCAST" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.`

I use the following API to connect. The custom schema name is specified in the `connection_string` variable

`retcode = SQLDriverConnect(pDbConnectionHandle->g_hDbc,
            NULL,
            connection_string,
            SQL_NTS,
            NULL, 0, NULL,
            SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);`

The same application creates a table in the schema, but `NUMCAST` function installed in the schema is not recognized. Could you tell what is missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to set the `CURRENT PATH` special register to include your schema. issue a db2 command like:

```
SET CURRENT PATH = "SYSIBM","SYSFUN","SYSPROC","SYSIBMADM","myschema"
```

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005877.html

Comment: Thanks, infact this has to be given the "connection_string" like this: CurrentFunctionPath="SYSIBM", "SYSFUN", SANISH_SCHEMA;